# PHP Recursion: The reason behind the values

Tags: php, string, recursion

This is about learning recursion in PHP and I was wondering why the value of $pwr variable decrements initially then increments again once it reaches zero.

> *code below is about to the Power of:

```
function toThePower($num, $pwr){
   if($pwr == 0){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return $num * toThePower($num, $pwr-1);
  }
}
```

Example:

echo toThePower(2,3);

result: 8

As I was looking the values of $pwr variable:

before: $pwr = 3,2,1
after: $pwr = 1,2,3

Why did $pwr variable incremented? We are only decrementing $pwr variable here right?

I know this is a noob question but I badly need an explanation on how it is currently working.

Comment: What are you even talking about here with “before” and “after” …? Explain what “looking at” the variables means exactly, where, when and how you are doing that.

Comment: how do you print the values?

Comment: Here you go, the one with the comment:function toThePower($num, $pwr){
   if($pwr == 0){
      return 1;
    }else{
    
    echo $pwr; // before
      $temp =  $num * toThePower($num, $pwr-1);
     echo $pwr; //after
  }
}

Comment: Well that is actually the basic principle of recursion at work here … The variable does not get incremented, you are returning to an earlier point here where it still _had_ that higher value.

Comment: The value of $pwr does not change between “before” and “after”. It changes only within the next “level” of the recursion. `toThePower($num, $pwr-1)` - here the _value_ of $pwr minus one is passed into the function as parameter, so _inside_ that next function execution, $pwr will be one lower, but that does not change the value of the “outer” $pwr.